# Debugging Nagios Configuration

Tags: configuration, nagios

I have this nagios configuration that won't validate.

I'm trying to set up contacts and the various groups of contacts.  My Contacts are based off of my `generic-manager` template:

> #### define contact {
>
> ```
>     contact_name                    generic-manager
>     name                            generic-manager
>     email                           defaultemail@mydomain.com
>     alias                           Manager Template
>     service_notification_period     hours
>     host_notification_period        hours
>     service_notification_options    w,c,r                        
>     host_notification_options       d,u,r                        
>     service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email,             
>     host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email,
>     register                        0 }
> ```

My Contact definition:

> #### define contact {
>
> ```
>     use                             generic-manager  
>     name                            manager-1  
>     contact_name                    First Manager  
>     contactgroups                   branch  
>     email                           branchmanager@mydomain.com }
> ```

Contact Group definition:

> #### define contactgroup {
>
> ```
>     contactgroup_name       branch
>     alias                   Contacts for Branch  
>     members                 admins,manager-1 }
> ```

When I verify the configuration `nagios -v /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` I get the following errors.

Error: Could not find any contact matching 'manager-1'
Error: Could not expand member contacts specified in contactgroup

I've made sure that everything is spelled correctly, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#contact "contact_name" should be used for the short name (that is used in groups etc.) and "alias" for the longer name. So you should change it to:

```
contact_name manager-1
alias First Manager
```

Also, you should use either "contactgroups" in a contact or "members" in a contactgroup, not both. While it will not break anything now, it might lead to confusion later if you update only one and find that it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

in your contact def. can you replace this:

```
contact_name First Manager
```

with that:

```
contact_name manager-1
```

?